# python serial library issue with ser.write() command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am looking for a solution to combine a string of integers(let's say, *'0000'* and *'1000'* for example). But I need to encode to bytes anything that is sent through ser.write() with the `b` attribute that goes next to the string I want to send, which will give something like :
`ser.write(b'0000')`if I want to send 0000

Now , I want to add a for loop that changes each time the integers that will be sent, but I can't figure out how to add a string variable with the ser.write() command AND the b at the begining.

What I would like to achieve is something like

`ser.write(myString encoded in bytes)`

Thanks for your help !

I looked at other similar posts, and tried such things as :

1. `ser.write(f"b'myString'")`didn't work...
2. the `.format()` method (neither did it work)
3. And the %-formatting method (also get an error)

Here are the errors I get when I try one of these 3 methods :

````
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '1111101000'```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the device on the other end of the line wants text encoded as UTF-8 bytes, `.encode()` it (as the error says):

```
ser.write(f"hëllo world".encode("utf-8"))
```

IOW, for a loop, you might do

```
for x in range(100):
    ser.write(f"{x:04d}".encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: yeah I'm soooo dumb. I didn't think about the utf-8 encoding... Anyways It works now ! Many thanks